# Error building java project

Tags: java, netbeans6.8

I have tryied to build my project in netbeans 6.8/ windows xp, and I've received this errors:

```
..\nbproject\build-impl.xml:452: The following error occurred while executing this line:

..\nbproject\build-impl.xml:224: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.output for details.
```

The lines are, respectively:
452:

```
`<j2seproject3:javac gensrcdir="${build.generated.sources.dir}"/>`
```

224:

```
<javac debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" destdir="@{destdir}" encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" fork="${javac.fork}" includeantruntime="false" includes="@{includes}" source="${javac.source}" sourcepath="@{sourcepath}" srcdir="@{srcdir}" target="${javac.target}" tempdir="${java.io.tmpdir}">
```

I have tried to reinstall netbeans, java, and anything more...but I can't resolve this error. 
Do someone know how can I fix it?

All the best!

Leandro

Comment: And what does it say in the compiler error output?

Comment: Everything it gave me was warnings like this one:
warning: sun.awt.image.ImageDecoder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

Comment: Which JDK are you using ? Is sun.awt.ImageDecoder in there ? It would really help if you posted the output

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, Netbeans screws up the build file generation
(generation of `build-impl.xml` from `build.xml`).

If **may** help to remove buid-impl.xml, close project, restart Netbeans, open project. But in some cases Netbeans fails to regenerate this file.

What will help in **most cases** is:

- Create **new** project in different location (with same name if you whish);
- Open old and new project;
- Copy all packages from old project, and paste to new project
  (try **with** refactoring, but when fails, try without.);
- Adopt manually all project settings from old project into new.
- Forget the old project and delete it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's resolved. I haven't seen that one warning was for a library not found. I just give to netbeans that library and my code is compiled well.

Sorry guys
Leandro.

Comment: 2 things. 1) Please post your output if you are having problems and people ask for it. 2) Do not answer your own question, just edit your question and put your updates there. Thanks